# Does $u\in H^{3/2}(\Omega)$ imply continuity of $\nabla u\cdot\overrightarrow{n}$ across an interior interface?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity

When investigaing the regularity of certain functions, I encountered this problem:

if $u\in H^{3/2}([0,1]\times [0,1])$, 
what can we say about the continuity of $\nabla u\cdot\overrightarrow{n}$
across a line segment inside the domain, where $\overrightarrow{n}$ is the unit normal ?

Without loss of generality, we formulate the problem as below:

> Let $\Omega$ be the unit square in two dimensions
>   and let $\gamma$ denote a vertical line segment inside $\Omega$.
>
> If $u\in H^{3/2}(\Omega)$, can we deduce that 
>   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{\gamma^+}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{\gamma^-} \;\;\; ?$$

The subscripts $\gamma^+$ and $\gamma^-$ denote traces from left and right sides of $\gamma$, respectively.

**Here we assume that**
$$  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{\gamma^+}\in L^2(\gamma),\quad
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{\gamma^-}\in L^2(\gamma).$$
Note that this assumption is not redundant because trace theorem does not hold for $H^{1/2}(\Omega)$ with index $1/2$.

What if the assumption above is weakened into:
$$  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{\gamma^+}\in H^{-1/2}(\gamma),\quad
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{\gamma^-}\in H^{-1/2}(\gamma) \;\;\; ?$$

The question was asked in MSE last year but there is still no response, so I plan to ask here.

Comment: If you can bound the trace, you can approximate H^3/2 by smooth functions and pass the identity to the limit.

Comment: Sounds true, so the property does not hold for $H^{3/2-\delta}$ in general for any $\delta>0$.

Comment: @FanZheng No, it is not true because trace theorem does not hold for $H^{1/2}(\Omega)$, so the question is still nontrivial.

Comment: Remark. For Lipschitz domain $\Omega$ and $H^s(\Omega)$, the index with trace theorem is $s\in (\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the corner case. But then how do you define the trace in the first place?

Comment: It is fine because it was **assumed** that those traces are in $L^2$ in my post.

Comment: @FanZheng: could you please elaborate on your statement that "he trace does live in any Sobolev space below L2". In what sense? I am genuinely interested in this, because some time ago I was looking at some mixed boundary elliptic problems where regularity goes strictly under $3/2$, but the thing that saved the day was that away from the boundary, the solution was in $H^1$.

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not, but if $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$, then the normal derivatives will necessarily be in $H^{-1/2}(\gamma)$ and will be equal.

Comment: @GrahamCox Thanks but the case I'm interested in is $\Delta u\notin L^2(\Omega)$.